# Pandas replace selective data with new set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l have a digital elevation map Tiff file and by using `Gdal` module and `pandas` , all data are written in `dem.xlsx` excel file and my purpose is to replace max value of each row with `1` ,other positive values with `0` and negative values with `-9999` and then ,write the result in new excel. However, l could not able to replace values and write in new excel.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import gdal

layer = gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/owrasa/PycharmProjects/den/dem/dem.tif")
arr=layer.ReadAsArray()
df=pd.DataFrame(arr)

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter(
    'dem.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer1, 'Sheet1')
writer1.save()
df=pd.read_excel("dem.xlsx")
writer2 = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')


for i in df:
    for a in range(2851):
        if i>0 and i<df.ix[a].max():
            df.replace(i,0)
        elif i==df.ix[a].max():
            df.replace(i,1)
        else:
            df.replace(i,-9999)

    df.to_excel(writer2, 'Sheet1')
    writer2.save()
```

dem excel file has 2098 row x 2851 column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [313]: df
Out[313]:
   a   b  c
0  3   2  3
1 -8  -5  8
2  7   1 -7
3 -4  -7  3
4 -2 -10  0

In [314]: df[df.ge(0)].fillna(-9999).where(df<0, df.eq(df.max(1), 0).astype(int))
Out[314]:
        a       b       c
0     1.0     0.0     1.0
1 -9999.0 -9999.0     1.0
2     1.0     0.0 -9999.0
3 -9999.0 -9999.0     1.0
4 -9999.0 -9999.0     1.0
```

if you need integers:

```
In [320]: df[df.ge(0)].fillna(-9999).astype(int).where(df<0, df.eq(df.max(1), 0).astype(int))
Out[320]:
      a     b     c
0     1     0     1
1 -9999 -9999     1
2     1     0 -9999
3 -9999 -9999     1
4 -9999 -9999     1
```

Explanation:

`VirtualDF1`: Let's replace all negative elements with `-9999`:

```
In [316]: df[df.ge(0)].fillna(-9999)
Out[316]:
        a       b       c
0     3.0     2.0     3.0
1 -9999.0 -9999.0     8.0
2     7.0     1.0 -9999.0
3 -9999.0 -9999.0     3.0
4 -9999.0 -9999.0     0.0
```

`VirtualDF2`: Using this trick we can replace all row's maximums with ones (`1`) and other elements with zeros (`0`):

```
In [317]: df.eq(df.max(1), 0).astype(int)
Out[317]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  1
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
```

and finally using [DataFrame.where()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method we can choose elements from the `VirtualDF1` if corresponding element in the original DF is negative or from the `VirtualDF2` otherwise...

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
df.eq(df.max(1), 0).sub(df.lt(0).mul(9999))
```

[image]

Comment: that is smart !

Comment: it could be useful ,however, there will be no two max value each row as example above, there are two max value at same row.l wonder for loop l used is wrong ? or structure not proper?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do that. However, pay attention to one point, this code will replace initial `nan` values with `-9999`.

```
# Create test data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Replace the max of each row for positive values by 1
# Divide each value by the maximum of the row, in consequence:
#  - the max is = 1
#  - negative values are nan since they have been filtered
#  - Remaining values are in the [0, 1[ interval
df = df[df>0].apply(lambda x: x / x.max(), axis=1)

# Replace remaining positive values by 0
df[df<1] = 0

# Replace negative values (nan) by -9999
df = df.fillna(-9999)

# Write the result to an Excel sheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'result')

# Before
#    A   B   C   D
# 0  72 -53  17  92
# 1 -33  95   3 -91
# 2 -79 -64 -13 -30
# 3 -12  40 -42  93
# 4 -61 -13  74 -12

# After
#         A       B       C       D
# 0     0.0 -9999.0     0.0     1.0
# 1 -9999.0     1.0     0.0 -9999.0
# 2 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0
# 3 -9999.0     0.0 -9999.0     1.0
# 4 -9999.0 -9999.0     1.0 -9999.0
```

Comment: What will happen in `x / x.max()` if `x.max() == 0`?

Comment: l tried your code and the result is not satisfactory as some rows has two or more max values.

Comment: @MaxU Oups, I think it's a bug, it will produce `nan` in this case. @ömersarı I do not understand since what is expected in case of row with equal max values in the original dataset. How can we choose between them. It think you should use the answer provided by MaxU.

Comment: it is a homework given by my instructor as he does not know Python and l m not sure about what purpose he has.